# Como leer más de una vez con el método System.in.read() en java?

Tags: java, entrada

lo que intento hacer es leer más de una vez carácter a carácter con el método `System.in.read()`.

La primera lectura la guardo en una variable tipo `char` con su respectiva conversión en el código `ASCII` y la muestro, pero a partir de la segunda lectura en adelante me toca colocar la sentencia `aux = (char)System.in.read();` dos veces seguidas para que funcione correctamente.

Aunque sé que esa es una solución quiero que me expliquen porqué sucede esto y si hay otra forma de solucionarlo para que se vea más elegante.

Sé que tiene que ver algo con el buffer porque en C++ también me pasó con el `getline()` y se solucionaba con `fflush(stdin);` pero acá la verdad no se.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
package ejemplo;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Ejemplo {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        char aux;
        aux = (char)System.in.read();//1ra lectura bien
        System.out.print(aux);

        aux = (char)System.in.read();// a partir de aqui son 2 sentencias
        aux = (char)System.in.read();
        System.out.print(aux);

        aux = (char)System.in.read();
        aux = (char)System.in.read();
        System.out.print(aux);

        aux = (char)System.in.read();
        aux = (char)System.in.read();
        System.out.print(aux);

        aux = (char)System.in.read();
        aux = (char)System.in.read();
        System.out.print(aux);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.in.read()` lee exactamente un `byte` del flujo de entrada (teclado en este caso).

Cuando tu tecleas un carácter, este se mete en dicho flujo de entrada una vez pulsas `enter`(intro). Esto hace que en dicho flujo se meta también un caracter de retorno de carro (`\n`)

Pongámonos en tu ejemplo. Cuando comienza la ejecución, el flujo esta vacío. Al teclear por ejemplo `H`+`Enter`, en el buffer entran dos bytes: `H`y `\n`.

La primera vez ejecutas un `System.in.read()`, con lo que obtienes `H` y se elimina del buffer. Pero este tiene todavía `\n`.

La siguiente vez, tecleas `J`+ `Enter`. En ese momento, el buffer contiene `\n`,`J` y `\n`.

Por eso, para obtener el siguiente `char` pulsado debes llamar dos veces a `System.in.read()`: La primera obtiene del buffer `\n` y la segunda ya obtiene `J`. Pero continúa quedando `\n` en el.

Espero haberme explicado bien... :)

**Edit**

Como comenta @PabloLozano, para leer del teclado es mucho mas cómodo usar `System.console().readLine()` y te evitarías todos estos problemas.

Comment: De hecho, el OP podría probar a usar `System.console().readLine()`, más sencillo que leer byte a byte

Comment: @PabloLozano si,hay otras opciones, pero entiendo que es cuestión mas de curiosidad que otra cosa :)

Comment: Por eso simplemente lo comento, en lugar de añadir una respuesta. Si quiere usar read(), está bien así.

Comment: @PabloLozano editada la respuesta para reflejarlo :)

Comment: Bueno en realidad la duda era por curiosidad, sé que hay métodos más sencillos como el Scanner, el System console que mencionan, entre otros, pero me gusta saber hasta lo más básico.

Gracias a todos.. saludos!